# Django Push Notification for IOS safari

Tags: angularjs, django, push-notification, safari, apple-push-notifications

I used [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) for implementing push notifications in `Django` server.

I have implemented `GCM` for my `AngularJS` webapp and its working great on chrome. For safari I'm following [this post](https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/safari-push-notifications-ec171bdf6ead) for implementing `APNS` part but I get this error:

```
"POST /v1/pushPackages/web.com.example HTTP/1.1" 200 5722
{u'logs': [u'downloading push notification package failed']}
```

This is my **views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def getPushPackage(request):
    try:
        print "Here -- > Hello"
        filename = '/pushNotifications/static/pushPackage.zip'
        zipfile = open(settings.BASE_DIR+filename, 'rb')
        response = HttpResponse(content=zipfile)
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' %(settings.BASE_DIR+filename)
        print "Here -- > Done"
        return response
        # return HttpResponse(content=zipfile, content_type='application/force-download')
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
        return Response(str(e))
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
url(r'^v2/pushPackages/web.com.example', views.getPushPackage),
url(r'^v1/log', views.printPushError),
```

This is my **Controller**

```
var checkRemotePermission = function (permissionData) {
    console.log(permissionData.permission);
    if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
        // This is a new web service URL and its validity is unknown.
        window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
            'https://x.x.x.x:1234', // The web service URL.
            'web.com.example',
            {}, // Data that you choose to send to your server to help you identify the user.
            checkRemotePermission         // The callback function.
        );
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
        console.log("here user denial");
        // The user said no.
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
        // The web service URL is a valid push provider, and the user said yes.
        console.log("here");
        console.log(permissionData.deviceToken);
        // permissionData.deviceToken is now available to use.
    }
};

// functions end
if(browser == "Safari")
{
    console.log( "In safari" );
    if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
        var permissionData = window.safari.pushNotification.permission('web.com.example');
        checkRemotePermission(permissionData);
    }
}
```